# How to specify an absolute screen location in a storyboard (not relative to original control position)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a UserControl with a storyboard embedded in it. There will be a few of these UserControls spread around the screen, and when the user clicks on them I'd like the selected one to animate itself into the middle of the screen.

I am using a Storyboard inside the user control to do this. However, I cannot for the life of me work out how to say inside my Storyboard "move to screen location 200,200". The RenderTransform->Translate is always local to the original position of the control, as is Projection->Global Offset. Any ideas?

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need Canvas for screen location with attached properties Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200"

```
      <Storyboard x:Name="animation"
          Storyboard.TargetName="myControl"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" >
        <DoubleAnimation To="200" Duration="0:0:10" />
     </Storyboard>
```

I think the embedded storyboard is not a good idea. This animation works only with Canvas and when someone place it in a grid or stack panel, an exception will be thrown.

[More info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response - am I right in thinking that this storyboard has to go in the parent, rather than in the user control itself? I think this might be where I've been going wrong with this idea.